# Getting all text elements with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get all text elements with selenium. This is my try, it return None.

```
    try:
        description = browser.find_element_by_class_name("jobDescriptionText").text
    except:
        description = "None"
        descriptions.append(description)
        print(description)
    
    time.sleep( 5 )
```

I would like to get all the text between these elements. How I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably confused yourself link is just a string and checking the html i think you meant `id` not `class`, Use:

```
description = browser.find_element_by_id("jobDescriptionText").text
```

Instead of:

```
description = link.find_element_by_class_name("jobDescriptionText").text
```

Comment: First one still not working, I edit and add my full code above

Comment: Try the code now

Comment: Ah yes it works ;)! Thanks!